# Web Scraping using Beautiful Soup Onclick tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, onclick

I am trying to download a table from a website which has a dropdown menu for download (onclick HTML tag).

How do I execute the onlick option to automatically download the table? Here is the code I have written:

```py
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = 'https://www.iexindia.com/marketdata/rtm_market_snapshot.aspx'
request = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

webpage = urlopen(request).read()
soup = soup(webpage, "lxml")

table=soup.find_all('table')[1]

properties = table.find_all('a', onclick=True)[0]
```

This is the tag that I need to execute:

```html
<a alt="Excel" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$find('ctl00_InnerContent_reportViewer').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');" style="color:#3366CC;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;padding:3px 8px 3px 8px;display:block;white-space:nowrap;text-decoration:none;" title="Excel">
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

`BeautifulSoup` is only used for HTML parsing.

To interact with the webpage, you should use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This script will save the table to `data.xls` file:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
url = 'https://www.iexindia.com/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID={control_id}&Mode=true&OpType=Export&FileName=MarketMinute&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=EXCELOPENXML'

with requests.session() as s, open('data.xls', 'wb') as f_out:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get('https://www.iexindia.com/marketdata/rtm_market_snapshot.aspx', headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    img = soup.select_one('img[src*="ControlID"]')
    control_id = re.search(r'ControlID=([a-f\d]+)', img['src'])[1]

    f_out.write( s.get(url.format(control_id=control_id), headers=headers).content )
```

Screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!Works Perfectly. Could you tell me how did you take the HTML?

Comment: @PoojaBhateley I monitored where the page is making requests when clicking on the Save button. But this URL has `ControlID=` parameter which is changing each session, so it was quite tricky.

Comment: @AndreyKesely, could you help me with scraping the data from this url also, by using the same logic of clicking on the download option in excel or csv-http://wbes.nrldc.in/Report/RTMIndex